# set gamma when lightdm starts

Tags: 14.04, xorg, lightdm

I want to set the following when booting lightdm: xrandr --output eDP1 --gamma 0.8:0.8:0.65.

I have tried:

- Creating a startup application (works, but only after loggin in.
- setting display-setup-script in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-custom.conf (with both xrandr + bashscript.sh + xgamma)
- Custom xorg.conf with gamma under Monitor.

Really cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have tried on both laptop (intel GPU) + desktop (nvidia driver).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me recently. I had a similar problem and wanted to set the display scaling on my 4k monitor because the fonts were too small.

First, create a `lightdm.conf` file in the `lightdm` config folder

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script = /etc/lightdm/monitor-config.sh
```

Then create the `monitor-config.sh` script in the same folder

/etc/lightdm/monitor-config.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 0.7x0.7
```

Once you do this, restart lightdm and you should see that the changes have been applied

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```